# Google Compute Engine: how to find why load balancing health checks are failing?

Tags: load-balancing, google-compute-engine

I've been trying to create a Google Compute Engine network load balancing health check for an HTTPS (port `443`) endpoint. The same endpoint when accessed over HTTP (port `80`) is healthy. Also, the HTTPS endpoint, when accessed for example with `curl` correctly returns a `200` OK response, which would be the required condition for an healthy check.

It would be extremely helpful if there was a way to access a more detailed error report of why the health check is failing, because it's probably something quite easy to fix, but the total lack of detailed information in the web interface makes it random guess work. Trying to research information about where to find detailed information about why a health check is failing I have come up empty.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is because load balancer health checks don't currently support HTTPS.

Comment: That would explain the observed behaviour @DavidM. I am still hopping we'll get some official reply from a Google engineer regarding this, since they are supposed to monitor the ``google-compute-engine`` tag. Meanwhile I have made an endpoint available through HTTP for health check purposes as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

The 200 ok is related to the health check, but if your TCP connection is not closed properly, this can cause this issue. If you run this command: tcpdump -A -n host your_host ip, you can confirm that the TCP connection is closed with a FIN/ACK status. If you see [R] flag in the output, it indicates that the connection is being reset instead of closing properly.

For more information, visit this link https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/health-checks#steps_to_set_up_health_checks